# Trying to figure out how to code a multiplayer game

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

it's my first time creating a multiplayer game, and I'm trying to understand how it works. I'm programming a multiplayer card game in React Native using Firebase database. I have a `dealCards` function that activates in the `useEffect` on the game page when all players are in the game. The issue is that the function runs three times, matching the number of players in the game.

Since the players host the game, the function gets called every time the `useEffect` loads a player.

For example, everything happens very quickly, but you can observe the renders on the screen. The first player entering the game deals the cards, followed by the second, resulting in visible card changes, and this sequence continues.
How can I set it up to run just once?

The function:

```
 const dealCards=(playerOnGame,deck)=>{
    
    deck.shuffle()        
    
    //deal first card for all table
    for(let i=0;i<playerOnGame.length;i++){
        let card=deck.pop();
        if(playerOnGame[i].money!==0){
           
            playerOnGame[i].card1 = card

        }
        
    }

    
    //deal second card for all table
    for(let i=0;i<playerOnGame.length;i++){
        let card=deck.pop();
        if(playerOnGame[i].money!==0){
        playerOnGame[i].card2=card
        }
    }
    
    let newPlayersOnGame=[...playerOnGame]
    
    functions.playersInGameUpdating(newPlayersOnGame)
    
   // setAllCardOfPlayersInGame(newPlayersOnGame)
}
```

inside the game page:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dealCards()
}, [])
```

what i return :

```
     return(    
        <ImageBackground source={image}  resizeMode='cover' style={{height:'100%'}}>
        <SafeAreaView  >
                    
        <View style={styles.upRow}>
                       
         <ImageBackground
        //player1//position2
  
    source={require('../assets/circle2.png')}
    resizeMode='center'
    style={styles.circleCornerLeftUp}>

    {showCards ?(
    <View style={styles.fishCardRow}>
    <Image
    source={playersInTable[0].card1.cardImage}
    resizeMode='center'
    style={styles.fishCard}/>
     <Image
    source={playersInTable[0].card2.cardImage}
    resizeMode='center'
    style={styles.fishCard}/>
    </View>
    )
    :
    null
    }
     <Image
    source={playersInTable[0].character}
    resizeMode='center'
    style={styles.charcter}/>
    
                        <Text style={styles.charcterText}>{playersInTable[0].userName}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.moneyText}><MaterialCommunityIcons name="currency-ils" size={12} color="white" />{playersInTable[0].money.toFixed(2)}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.blindText}>{playersInTable[0].blind}</Text>
        </ImageBackground> 

         <ImageBackground
        //player2
    source={require('../assets/circle2.png')}
    resizeMode='center'
    style={styles.imageIconCircleUp}>

{showCards ?(
    <View style={styles.fishCardRow}>
    <Image
    source={playersInTable[1].card1.cardImage}
    resizeMode='center'
    style={styles.fishCard}/>
     <Image
    source={playersInTable[1].card2.cardImage}
    resizeMode='center'
    style={styles.fishCard}/>
    </View>
    )
    :
    null
    }
     <Image
                            source={playersInTable[1].character}
    resizeMode='center'
    style={styles.charcter}/>
                        <Text style={styles.charcterText}>{playersInTable[1].userName}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.moneyText}><MaterialCommunityIcons name="currency-ils" size={12} color="white" />{playersInTable[1].money.toFixed(2)}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.blindText}>{playersInTable[1].blind}</Text>
    </ImageBackground> 

 <ImageBackground
        //player3
    source={require('../assets/circle2.png')}
    resizeMode='center'
    style={styles.imageIconCircleUp}>

{showCards ?(
    <View style={styles.fishCardRow}>
    <Image
    source={playersInTable[2].card1.cardImage}
    resizeMode='center'
    style={styles.fishCard}/>
     <Image
    source={playersInTable[2].card2.cardImage}
    resizeMode='center'
    style={styles.fishCard}/>
    </View>
    )
    :
    null
    }
   <Image
    source={playersInTable[2].character}
    resizeMode='center'
    style={styles.charcter}/>
                        <Text style={styles.charcterText}>{playersInTable[2].userName}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.moneyText}><MaterialCommunityIcons name="currency-ils" size={12} color="white" />{playersInTable[2].money.toFixed(2)}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.blindText}>{playersInTable[2].blind}</Text>
    </ImageBackground>
```

Comment: Do you also have some code to share?

Comment: I just made an edit. In the function, what happens is that I update the array in the database with all the card values, and it's then displayed individually to each player on the screen.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or something where the behavior can be reproduced so we could play around with it?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: For example: https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/react-jsx

Comment: I would be happy to share the entire app with you in screen sharing and explain it to you if you can, I've been dealing with this problem for a long time.